# error executeSql

Tags: jquery, sqlite

I have received message "could not prepare statement" when try execute a select below
What is wrong my tx.executeSql?
What is correct syntax for executeSql?

```
var DB;
var tx;
var sql = "select nome from LivroDaBiblia;";
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        if (window.openDatabase) {
            DB = window.openDatabase('Biblia', '', 'App Database', 1000000, errorHandler);
            DB.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sql, [], function (trx, result) {
                }, errorHandler);
            });
            function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
                alert('Oops. Error was ' + error.message + ' (Code ' + error.code + ')');
                return false;
            };

        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Error handling code goes here.
        if (e == 2) {
            // Version number mismatch.
            alert("Invalid database version.");

        } else {
            alert("Unknown error " + e + ", please contact your local   ntative.");
        }
    }

    DB.close();

}); // JavaScript Document
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but looks to me like this line:

tx.executeSql(sql, [], function (trx, result)

should actually read as:

tx.executeSql(sql, [], function (**tx**, result)

Otherwise you're trying to call something you've not defined -- trx vs tx.